# Blazor Maui not displaying images with spaces or special characters

Tags: maui-blazor

I can display images that have no spaces nor special characters in their filenames but how am I supposed to display images that do have those? I tried the following and none worked for me using the latest versions and .Net 7:

Razor:

```
<img class="actor-image" src="@EncodedActorImagePath" />
```

None of the following works in the code behind:

```
// ActorImagePath = "images/actors/John Test.png"; // Yes, this file exists.

private string EncodedActorImagePath => Uri.EscapeDataString(ActorImagePath);

private string EncodedActorImagePath => ActorImagePath.Replace(" ", "%20");

private string EncodedActorImagePath => WebUtility.HtmlEncode(ActorImagePath);

private string EncodedActorImagePath => WebUtility.UrlEncode(ActorImagePath);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar issue about [spaces in static files (CSS, JS, images, etc.) not working in MAUI Blazor](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9181) on the github. And according to the comment in it, this problem is entirely specific to Blazor Hybrid.

I have create a new Blazor WebAssembly App to test, the image can be displayed in the browser even though there is a space in the image name. But the maui blazor display the razor page in the webview2.

In addition, this problem has been added into the .Net 8 planning. And you may need to change the image files' name to make them can be displayed in the maui blazor.

Comment: .Net 8 is planned for November, I can't wait that long so indeed, I guess I'll have to batch rename every file and also any references to it in the database and disallow any such future filenames. It also affects other static files it seems, I did not expect such a huge bug. Thank you.